# Access second table value through foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating a app in order to play around with ASP, MVC and the Entity Framework. I've been following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial, changing the data model to fit my needs.

I've got all users data showing on a page, within a table. In my model I have a separate table for the faculty the user is part of. On the page with the user details it's currently displaying the primary key from the faculty table. I would like to display the faculty name in it's place. How can I achieve this?

Using the code displayed below I expected to be able to use the following line of code to display the faculty name, but this displays a cell with an empty string due to the variable faculty is null.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.faculty.name)
```

If I was using PHP I would do something like this;

```
SELECT faculty_name
FROM   faculties
WHERE  user.school = faculties.id;
```

**users model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Purely_Servers.Models
{
    [Table("userTable")]
    public class user
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int house_number { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public int authorised { get; set; }
        public int school { get; set; }
        public int archived { get; set; }

        public virtual faculty faculty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**faculty model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Purely_Servers.Models
{
    [Table("facultyTable")]
    public class faculty
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**display the users school**

This is currently displaying a numeric value corresponding to the primary key of a record in the faculty table.

```
@model IEnumerable<Purely_Servers.Models.user>

@foreach (var item in Model){
    <tr>
        //other code
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.school)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**user controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Purely_Servers.DAL;
using Purely_Servers.Models;

namespace Purely_Servers.Controllers
{
    public class usersController : Controller
    {
        private serverContext db = new serverContext();

        // GET: users
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        // GET: users/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: users/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: users/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,first_name,last_name,email,house_number,street,city,postcode,authorised,school,archived")] user user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: users/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: users/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,first_name,last_name,email,house_number,street,city,postcode,authorised,school,archived")] user user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: users/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: users/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            user user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What behavior are you getting with the current code?

Comment: @probackpacker the current code is displaying a numeric value corresponding to the primary key in the faculty table

Comment: in your model, `school` is an `int` which is just storing a value, it is not a navigation property.  if you wish to show the contents of a navigation property, that property needs to actually be loaded and sent to the client.  Can you show the controller that loads the data here?

Comment: in fact, if `school` is a reference to the primary key of the `faculty` entity, it's out of place in the `user` entity.  how is that `school` variable getting it's value?

Comment: @AndrewCounts I've added the controller class to the question. The school variable is added along with the rest of the users details when the database is created with the server initializer - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713276/code-first-database-not-being-created-from-model

Comment: neither this code nor the link you posted is showing where the data for the `int school ...` parameter of your `user` is being populated.  I'll try to expand a bit on this in the answer I'm working up.

Comment: in fact, looking at your save action, I don't really even think you have saved the relationship between the user and the facility correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you have posted in more detail, it appears as though you are not maintaining the relationship between your `user` and `faculty` correctly.

In your `user`, you have a property `int school {get;set;}` which you suggest represents the foreign key of the facility the user belongs to.  This may indeed be true, but you didn't actually notify Entity Framework of that fact.  In practice, the `school` property would be unnecessary.

In your Create action, you accept the `int school` as a parameter (presumably an int derived from a dropdown).  you then proceed to save this as a value in the database, and Entity Framework is happy to do so, blind to the fact that this actually represents a relationship.

What you probably intend to do in your Create operation is something more like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Users.Add(user);
    // Find Faculty in the database and add the user to the faculty's collection.
    var faculty = db.Faculty.Find(school);
    faculty.users.add(user);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now, the `school` parameter is unnecessary, as it is a duplicate of the `faculty.id`

In your `Details` action, you can now use `Include()` to send the `faculty` along with the `user` like so:

```
user user = db.Users.Include(u => u.faculty).SingleOrDefault(u => u.id == id);
```

(Note that adding `Include` requires the use of `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Find`. If lazy loading is enabled, the `Include` isn't entirely necessary but *is* more efficient.)

With this in place, `item.faculty` is no longer `null`, and you can output `item.faculty.id`, `item.faculty.name`, etc.

Here is the link to the MSDN article on [Loading related entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the walk through. 
I've implemented the first part, its working great for new users, but its not been applied to users created using the seed method during the creation of the database.

Comment: I can't get the second part to work, specifically the Include()

Comment: you can use strings instead of the lambda for the include statement, i.e. `db.Users.Find(id).Include("Faculty");` but if you can use the lambda, it's more type safe.  what happens with the lambda?

Comment: also, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx for more info on loading related entities.  I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: In order to use the lambda expression in the `.Include()` method you have to add a using statement: `using System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: I already have entity included. I'll read the msdn and have a play. I understand what I need to do now thanks to you, so I'll accept the answer. Thanks for your help and happy new year :)

Answer (score 1):

`Html.DisplayFor` uses a lamdba expression. You declare `modelItem` but then use `item` in the expression. Your code should read:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.faculty.name)
```

Based on your edit:

More simply you could just use `@item.faculty.name`.

Comment: item refers to the loop which contains that line of code. I've expanded the code sample. I tried your suggestion and I get the message that model does not contain a definition for faculty.

Comment: Using your edit throws an exception -  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: When debugging, where is the null reference thrown? Is `item.faculty` null?

Comment: The exception is thrown on @item.faculty.name. In both the original code and your edit faculty is null.

Comment: Entity Framework is not retrieving the faculty entity associated with the user. Are you confident that you have a faculty entry with that id?

Comment: 100%. All data at this moment in time is hard coded.